# Using radix reports as blogdown posts, and saving .md from radix

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown, netlify

Many of my rmarkdown blogdown blog articles use netlify's ability to serve up .md files which RStudio makes from .Rmarkdown files.  I'll bet that I can serve up an .html file from a radix document, but these are large.  Is there a way to save the intermediate .md file produced by knitting to radix under RStudio, and would such a file be suitable for netlify?

Comment: A comment providing the reason for the downvote would help me improve the question.

Comment: 1. On Stack Overflow, I recommend that you just ignore downvoters who don't explain why; 2. If you like both radix and blogdown, you may wait for a few months till I figure out a better way to integrate them. For now, the only way is to render radix posts under the `static/` directory, and upload (or `git push`) the big .html files.

Comment: Thanks Yihui.  So I take it that saving the intermediate `.md` file won't do much good in this context.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.